# LatticeReduce of a linearly dependent basis

Tags: linear-algebra, lattices

```
l1 = {{-6327, 0, -2109}, {131, 0, -131}, {-6840, 0, 24929}};
LatticeReduce[l1]]
```

returns

```
{{1,0,0},{0,0,1}}.
```

How do I find the (probably not unique) $2\times 3$ integer matrix `n` such that

```
n.l1 == {{1,0,0},{0,0,1}}
```

Discussions in the literature of LLL reduction all seem to be for the linearly independent basis case. What does `LatticeReduce` do with a linearly dependent basis and is there any good discussion of this case in the published literature?

Thanks for the illuminating reply Daniel. Just to make sure I understand correctly here is how I would answer my original question using just the regular functions `LatticeReduce` & `HermiteDecomposition`.

Given a rank 2 basis in 3 dimensions

```
l1 = {{21, 22, -43}, {11, -13, 17}, {182, 19, -96}}

b1 = LatticeReduce[l1] = {{11, -13, 17}, {-32, -9, 26}}
```

If I want to find `n2` that satisfies

```
b1 = n2.l1
```

I let

```
l2 = HermiteDecomposition[l1] = {{{-1, 2, 0}, {11, -21, 0}, {-5, -7, 1}}, {{1, -48, 77}, {0, 515, -830}, {0, 0, 0}}}
```

and then solve `n1.l2[[2, 1;;2]] = b1`, or

```
n1 = Transpose[LinearSolve[b1.Transpose[l2[[2, 1;;2]]], b1.Transpose[b1]]] = {{11, 1}, {-32, -3}}
```

or

```
{u,w,v} = SingularValueDecomposition[l2[[2, 1 ;; 2]]]//N

n1 = b1.v.{{1/w[[1, 1]], 0}, {0, 1/w[[2, 2]]}, {0, 0}}.Transpose[u] = 
{{11., 1.}, {-32., -3.}}
```

and then

`n2 = n1.l2[[1, 1;;2]] = {{0, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}}`.

Comment: (1) `LatticeReduce` checks for independence and, if there are dependencies, preprocesses with `HermiteDecomposition`.

Comment: (2) There is an undocumented ``LinearAlgebra`ExtendedLatticeReduce`` which returns the multiplier matrix and reduced lattice. Unfortunately, due to a bug in the code (just noticed with this example), it only gives the multiplier matrix needed for handling the Hermite form vectors, not the full one that would arise from also using the `HermiteDecomposition` multiplier matrix. I need to fix that.

Comment: The method above looks good. I think I prefer `LinearSolve` to SVD though. The latter is either prone to bogging down (in exact arithmetic) or requiring a some trial and error on precision (approximate arithmetic) to recover correctly all integers.

Comment: Another method that is used is to give the lattice a "large" multiplier, then augment on the right or left with an identity matrix. It will have full rank and the reduced form will be a good approximation to the reduction of the original. One recovers the multipliers from the augmented part (the idea is identical to what is often taught for matrix inversion). Also remember to divide out the original multiplier from the original part to get the actual reduced form.